# PyPI how to supply text for `help()`?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Just finished writing my first Python package for work and made it pip installable.

How can I write a `help()` section like below? Ideally this would just point to my README as that is already written in .md and this package is for consumption in Jupyter.

Do I just put all of my README text in the package description?

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> help(pd)


Help on package pandas:

NAME
    pandas

DESCRIPTION
    pandas - a powerful data analysis and manipulation library for Python
    =====================================================================

    **pandas** is a Python package providing fast, flexible, and expressive data
    structures designed to make working with "relational" or "labeled" data both
    easy and intuitive. It aims to be the fundamental high-level building block ...

    Main Features
    -------------
    Here are just a few of the things that pandas does well:

      - Easy handling of missing data in floating point as well as non-floating
        point data...
```

Feedback welcome: https://pypi.org/project/gorpyter/

---

**ANSWER** this has been marked as duplicate and I provided a comprehensive answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529785/5739514

Comment: Hint: google "pydoc"

Comment: thanks @wim will check that out when i get home